# Oracle SQL assign if less than configured parameter

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below 2 tables:

assigned

| VK | PC | A | B | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VK1 | PC1 | A1 | null | 1 |
| VK2 | PC1 | A1 | A2 | 2 |
| VK3 | PC1 | A2 | null | 3 |
| VK4 | PC1 | A2 | null | 4 |
| VK5 | PC1 | null | A1 | 5 |
| VK6 | PC1 | null | A2 | 6 |

res

| PC | A | MAXI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PC1 | A1 | 2 |
| PC1 | A2 | 2 |

I would like to have the below desired output, based on this logic:

1. If B!=A, then assign B to C if the count of the value in B in the preceding rows order by rank is less than 'MAXI' in table res for that 'PC' and 'A'. If B=A or B is null, assign A to C.
2. After updating setting column C with the logic in point 1, if the count of any 'A's is less than 'MAXI' in table res, update the first null value to that 'A' until the count of 'A's is equal than 'MAXI' in res. Similarly, if the count of 'A's exceed 'MAXI' for any of the 'A's, set C to null the lowest assigned ranks until the condition is met.

Desired output:

| VK | PC | A | B | RANK | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VK1 | PC1 | A1 | null | 1 | A1 |
| VK2 | PC1 | A1 | A2 | 2 | A2 |
| VK3 | PC1 | A2 | null | 3 | A2 |
| VK4 | PC1 | A2 | null | 4 | A1 |
| VK5 | PC1 | null | A1 | 5 | null |
| VK6 | PC1 | null | A2 | 6 | null |

NOTE: row 4 was assigned to A1 instead of A2 because row 2 had to be assigned to A2 and thus row 4 exceeded the quota for A2. Quota for A1 was still 1 (less than 2), so could be assigned to A1. For row 5, there were already 2 A1s assigned (row 1 and 4), so the quota was exceeded and C had to be null.

EDIT: this is what I've tried so far.

```
with assigned (vk, pc, a, b, r) as(
select 'VK1', 'PC1', 'A1', null, 1 from dual union all
select 'VK2', 'PC1', 'A1', 'A2', 2 from dual union all
select 'VK3', 'PC1', 'A2', null, 3 from dual union all
select 'VK4', 'PC1', 'A2', null, 4 from dual union all
select 'VK5', 'PC1', null, 'A1', 5 from dual union all
select 'VK6', 'PC1', null, 'A2', 6 from dual),
res(pc, a, maxi) as(
select 'PC1', 'A1', 2 from dual union all
select 'PC1', 'A2', 2 from dual
)
, aux AS (
    SELECT
        a.*,
        coalesce(a.b, a.a) d,
        COUNT(coalesce(a.b, a.a)) OVER(
            PARTITION BY coalesce(a.b, a.a)
            ORDER BY
                r
        ) i,
        b.maxi
    FROM
        assigned   a
        LEFT JOIN res        b ON ( b.pc = a.pc
                             AND b.a = a.a )
)
SELECT
    a.*,
    case
        when i<=maxi then d
        else a end c
FROM
    aux a
order by r;
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?  What were the results?

Comment: I've just edited the question what the code I'm stuck with at the moment: I'm aware I'm nowhere near the solution, I can't get pass the step of counting the B value between unbounded and preceding in column A and compare it with the one in column MAXI in res.

Comment: @MarkStewart I've re-edited the question with another approach I've tried. I'm closer now to the solution but still stuck.

Comment: "If B!=A, then assign B to C if the sum of the value in B" this does not make sense as `B` is a string column and you cannot `SUM` strings.

Comment: @MT0 Sorry, I meant 'if the count'. I've just amended the question.

Comment: "2. After updating column A with the logic in point 1" Point 1 does not update column `A`; everything you mention in point 1 talks about setting the value in the new column `C`. Then: "if the count of any 'A's is less than 'MAXI' in table res, updating the first null value to that 'A'" however, column `A` does not have any `NULL` values. Please [edit] your question to includes the intermediate states between point 1 and point 2 and to clarify which columns you are talking about.

Comment: @MT0 sorry, I meant setting column C, that's the question amended. Column A does have 2 null values (rows 5 and 6 namely).

Comment: Column `A` does **NOT** have any `NULL` values in your sample query.

Comment: @MT0 oh, I see it know, I had mistyped the query. That's it amended now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic appears to be something like this:

```sql
WITH res_rows ( pc, a, maxi, total ) AS (
  SELECT pc, a, maxi, SUM( maxi ) OVER( PARTITION BY pc )
  FROM   res
  WHERE  maxi > 0
UNION ALL
  SELECT pc, a, maxi - 1, total FROM res_rows WHERE maxi > 1
),
p1 ( vk, pc, a, b, r, c, rn, pc_r ) AS (
  SELECT a.*,
         COALESCE(b, a),
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pc, COALESCE(b, a) ORDER BY r),
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pc ORDER BY r)
  FROM   assigned a
),
p2 ( vk, pc, a, b, r, c, rn ) AS (
  SELECT p1.vk,
         p1.pc,
         p1.a,
         p1.b,
         p1.r,
         r.a,
         CASE
         WHEN r.a IS NULL
         THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY p1.pc
                ORDER BY CASE WHEN r.a IS NULL THEN p1.r END
              )
         ELSE p1.rn
         END
  FROM   p1
         LEFT OUTER JOIN res_rows r
         ON ( p1.pc = r.pc AND p1.c = r.a AND p1.rn = r.maxi AND p1.pc_r <= total )
),
missing ( pc, a, rn ) AS (
  SELECT pc,
         a,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY pc ORDER BY ROWNUM )
  FROM   (
    SELECT pc, a, maxi FROM res_rows
    MINUS
    SELECT pc, c, rn FROM p2 WHERE c IS NOT NULL
  )
)
SELECT p2.vk,
       p2.pc,
       p2.a,
       p2.b,
       p2.r,
       COALESCE( m.a, p2.c ) AS c
FROM   p2
       LEFT OUTER JOIN missing m
       ON ( p2.pc = m.pc AND p2.c IS NULL AND p2.rn = m.rn )
ORDER BY r
```

Which outputs:

> | VK | PC | A | B | R | C |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | VK1 | PC1 | A1 |  | 1 | A1 |
> | VK2 | PC1 | A1 | A2 | 2 | A2 |
> | VK3 | PC1 | A2 |  | 3 | A2 |
> | VK4 | PC1 | A2 |  | 4 | A1 |
> | VK5 | PC1 |  | A1 | 5 |  |
> | VK6 | PC1 |  | A2 | 6 |  |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e7eadbc84340448e68f8db949241730a)*

Comment: yeah, I think it works fine, thanks! I would need to add a column in the input with an 'A' value which is going to be forbidden, if populated. Should I post it in a separate question? Also, is a cursor not preferable is this kind of cases where the logic becomes complex?